# Google Cloud Datastore : Composite Index : Order by does not seems to work

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, composite-index

I am using Google Cloud datastore with (C#) .NET Code, I have table called Audit in Datastore with following columns

ID/Name (long), ID (long), ActionType (String), GroupType (String), DateTime (TimeStamp), CompanyID (long), UserID (long), ObjectID (long), IsDeleted (boolean)

FYI, Both ID/Name and ID contains same information

I want to run GQL query like this

> SELECT * FROM Audit WHERE GroupType='XYZ' AND ActionType='CREATED' AND  CompanyID=152738292 and IsDeleted=false Order by ID

I don't seem be get right composite key and keep getting "Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query"

Here is the composite index created using index.yaml.

```
- kind: Audit

  properties:
  - name: ID
    direction: desc
  - name: IsDeleted
  - name: CompanyID
    direction: desc
  - name: GroupType
  - name: ActionType
```

Any Help on this subject would be appreciated!!

Let me know if you need additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query you need a composite index where `ID` is the last element, and its sort order matches the sort order in your query. For example:

```
- kind: Audit
  properties:
  - name: IsDeleted
  - name: CompanyID
    direction: desc
  - name: GroupType
  - name: ActionType
  - name: ID
```

(ID is implicitly sorted ascending in this index definition.)

Comment: Thanks Ed, It worked!! I can now run query like SELECT * FROM Audit WHERE CompanyID=167282 AND GroupType='XYZ' AND ActionType='CREATED' AND IsDeleted=false Order by ID desc LIMIT 5

Comment: @ED - whats the secret sauce here? I had the same problem and moving the order by field to the bottom of the index definition worked out..it must be something silly I miss.. trying to understand what that is..

Comment: There's some info here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_configuration. Or you can use `gcloud` to help you determine what indexes you'll need (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/). If you make a query that requires an index you don't have, the error message should also recommend an index for you.